# Template instantiation in GNU C++ and Clang

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, instantiation, clang++

Looks like the rules for template instantiation in Clang (3.8) and GNU C++ (4.9) are not the same. Here is an example:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <bool>
class Assert {
  Assert();          // private constructor for Assert<false>
};

template <>
class Assert<true> { // implicit public constructor for Assert<true>
};

template <size_t N>
class A {
};

template <class T, size_t N>
T foo(A<N>) {
  return T(N - 1);
}

template <class T>
T foo(A<0>) {        // foo is not defined for N=0
  Assert<false>();
  return T(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  foo<int>(A<3>());
  return 0;
}
```

This minimal example shows a template function, `foo`, that is generalized over a type `T` and a natural number `N`. This function is not defined for `N=0`, so I'd like to use the `Assert` class to signal a compiler error if it is used this way.

This code is accepted by the GNU compiler (and by Visual C++ 2015, as well), but Clang gives an error for "calling a private constructor of class `Assert<false>`".

So who is right? As I see it, there is no call for `foo<T,0>`, so there is no need to instantiate this template...

EDIT: Accepting Clang's interpretation of the standard, what is a canonical way to enforce compile-time checks on template parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe clang is correct, since `Assert<false>` is not a dependent type.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

> Non-dependent names are looked up and bound at the point of template definition. This binding holds even if at the point of template instantiation there is a better match:

Don't make specializations that cannot be valid.  Make them general purpose and use static_assert (with a dependent value) to check for invalid template argument types/values.   `static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value)` or `static_assert(N != 0)`

Comment: So `Assert<false>` is looked up and checked even if `foo<T,0>` is never instantiated? Isn't that a lot of extra work? Anyway, given that it works like this, what is a standard way for a compiler assertion on a template parameter? (I've edited the question accordingly.)

Comment: @vukung Actually it's less work, because the compiler only has to look up `Assert<false>` once, when the template is defined, rather than every time the template is instantiated.

Comment: Why would you write code that would never be used?  That sounds like a lot of extra work for YOU.

Answer (score 5):

> Accepting Clang's interpretation of the standard, what is a canonical way to enforce compile-time checks on template parameters?

You can drop the "specialization"/overload of `foo()` for `A<0>` and define the general template as follows:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T foo(A<N>) {
  Assert<N != 0>();
  return T(N - 1);
}
```

With C++11 you don't need to define your own static Assert and can use the language provided `static_assert`:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T foo(A<N>) {
  static_assert(N!=0, "N must be positive");
  return T(N - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Both compilers are correct. As usual, this is controlled by [[temp.res]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8):

> Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template
>   to be checked. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a `constexpr if` statement ([stmt.if]) within a
>     template and the template is not instantiated, or
> - every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack, or
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend
>     on a template parameter, or
> - the interpretation of such a construct in the hypothetical instantiation is different from the interpretation of the
>     corresponding construct in any actual instantiation of the template.

Your template runs afoul of the third bullet point.

As to the correct solution, either a suitable `static_assert` can be used, or you can explicitly delete the undesirable overload:

```
template <class T>
T foo(A<0>) = delete;
```

The former allows better error messages, the latter plays more nicely with other metaprogramming.